# ERROR: Failed to resolve ExpandableLayout

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to import an existing project in android studio but i'm facing below error

```
Could not find com.github.SilenceDut:ExpandableLayout:1.2.0.
```

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

**FYI**, **`SilenceDut:ExpandableLayout`** is deprecated.

You should add below in Project level **`build.gradle`** section.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
         maven { url "https://jitpack.io" } // Need this
    }
}
```

Note - `compile` is old. Use **`implementation`**.

```
implementation 'com.github.SilenceDut:ExpandableLayout:1.2.0'
```